# sleekXMPP: Get list of looged in users on XMPP Server

Tags: xmpp

I am new to python & sleekxmpp scripting and would like to know how to pass this iq stanza (XEP-0133: Service administration - Get Online Users) using python (mainly the node in below stanza):

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html#get-online-users-list

---

```
<iq from='bard@shakespeare.lit/globe'
    id='get-online-users-list-1'
    to='shakespeare.lit'
    type='set'
    xml:lang='en'>
  <command xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands' 
           action='execute'
           node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-online-users-list'/>
</iq>
```

---

What I tried:

```
iq = self .make_iq_get(queryxmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands', ito=self.domain, ifrom=self.jid, iq='')
response = iq.send()
print ('response = %s' % response)
```

Running above code in python is always resulting in IqError.

Can anyone please explain how to pass above iq stanza's xmlns, action and node information into make_iq_get ??

Please Help!!

Comment: You are creating a `get` IQ stanza but appear to want a `set` statement. `make_iq_get` makes a `query` IQ stanza but you want a `command` element and not a `query` element under the `iq` element and you don't appear to have created the `command` node at all. Print the `iq` stanza you are generating above and you should see what I mean.

Comment: I am not trying to set. Instead, I am trying to get list of online users on XMPP servers using make_iq_get command.

Comment: The snippet you pasted is clearly `type='set'`. But that's not the only issue as I indicated. Print out the XML stanza represented by your `iq` variable and compare it to what you need to send and you'll see the difference. I expect your `iq` stanza looks something like this: `<iq from=self.jid to=self.domain type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands'/></iq>`.

Comment: Yes, what you are expecting is correct. Am I passing wrong arguments to get information from XMPP server? What I am doing might be completely wrong. How do I pass 'action' and 'node' of iq stanza to make_iq_get command (Any example would help me please)?

Comment: You aren't creating an IQ `get` stanza so perhaps the `make_iq_get` function isn't the right place to start? Have you tried looking at what `make_iq_get` is doing internally to see how to build IQ stanzas more "manually"?

Comment: Thank You! I will have a look. Is it possible to give me a piece of code using 'get-online-users-list' iq node and make_iq_get / make_iq_set?

Comment: I could quite likely write the code for you but this isn't a code writing service (and I have no experience with sleekxmpp other than looking at it for this, and a few other, questions). You just need to actually look at the request you are trying to send and what the functions that you are calling actually do.

Comment: I was able to get list of admin commands with below code:
`print self['xep_0050'].get_commands(domain)`

To execute command, I have used following code:
`print self['xep_0050'}.send_command(domain, "http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-online-users-list")`

But, output of this does not list any users.
However, admin#get-online-users-num give the number as '4'. Am I missing anything here? Please Help!!

Comment: Does adding a `from` argument help? Other than that I have no ideas offhand.

Comment: Yes, adding a 'form' argument helped. Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

Following code has solved my above problem:

1st line of code returns you a form to be filled, 2nd line returns a session id which is used in last line of code

```
    iq = self['xep_0050'}.send_command(domain, "http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-online-users-list")
sessionid = iq['command']['sessionid'] 

form = self.xmpp.plugin['xep_0004'].make_form(ftype='submit')
    field = form.add_field(
            ftype='hidden',
            type='hidden',
            var='FORM_TYPE',
            value=ADMIN)
    field['type'] = 'hidden'
    form.add_field(var='max_items', value='100')

print self['xep_0050'}.send_command(domain, "http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-online-users-list", sessionid=sessionid, payload=form)
```